# How to write a while loop function in python for winsorizing

Tags: python, while-loop, scipy

I have the following function:

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize 
import pandas as pd

# winsorize function
def winsor_try1(var, lower, upper):
    var = winsorize(var,limits=[lower,upper])
    ''' 
    Outliers Calculation using IQR 
    ''' 
    q1, q3= np.percentile(var, [25, 75])                 # q1,q3 calc
    iqr = q3 - q1                                        # iqr calc
    lower_bound = round(q1 - (1.5 * iqr),3)              # lower bound
    upper_bound = round(q3 + (1.5 * iqr),3)              # upper bound
    outliers = [x for x in var if x < lower_bound or x > upper_bound]  
    print('These would be the outliers:', set(outliers),'\n',
          'Total:', len(outliers),'.Upper bound & Lower bound:', lower_bound,'&',upper_bound)

# the variable 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': [1,1,2,5,5,2,5,4,8,2,5,1,41,2,1,4,4,1,1,4,1,2,15,21,5,1,8,22,1,5,2,5,256,5,6,2,2,8,452]})
```

I would like to write a `while loop` function where I would like to apply function `winsor_try1` on the variable `df['age']`, starting at `lower = .01` & `upper = .01` until `len(outliers) = 0.`

My rationale is: as long as `len(outliers) > 0`, I would like the function to be repeated until I can find the limit until the outliers in the `age` distribution becomes 0.

Desired output would be something like this:

```
print('At limit =', i, 'there is no more outliers presented in the age variable.')
```

`i` = the limit where `len(outliers) = 0`.

Comment: If you're looking for `upper` and `lower` amounts which result in no outliers, why not calculate those from the distribution? e.g. `winsorize(var,limits=[lower_bound,upper_bound])`, and calculate `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` the way described in the question. Seems like it would be easier than looping over multiple lower/upper bound values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than writing a `while` loop yourself, you can think of this as a scalar root finding problem and use [scipy.optimize.root_scalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar 

# winsorize function
def winsor_try1(var, lower, upper):
    ''' 
    Compute the number of IQR outliers
    ''' 
    var = winsorize(var,limits=[lower,upper])
    q1, q3= np.percentile(var, [25, 75])                 # q1,q3 calc
    iqr = q3 - q1                                        # iqr calc
    lower_bound = round(q1 - (1.5 * iqr),3)              # lower bound
    upper_bound = round(q3 + (1.5 * iqr),3)              # upper bound
    outliers = [x for x in var if x < lower_bound or x > upper_bound]  
    return len(outliers)

# the variable 
var = np.asarray([1,1,2,5,5,2,5,4,8,2,5,1,41,2,1,4,4,1,1,4,1,2,15,21,5,1,8,22,1,5,2,5,256,5,6,2,2,8,452])

def fun(i):
  # try to find `i` at which there is half an outlier
  # it doesn't exist, but this should get closer to the transition
  return winsor_try1(var, i, i) - 0.5

# root_scalar tries to find the argument `i` that makes `fun` return zero
res = root_scalar(fun, bracket=(0, 0.5))

eps = 1e-6
print(winsor_try1(var, res.root + eps, res.root + eps))  # 0
print(winsor_try1(var, res.root - eps, res.root - eps))  # 6
res.root  # 0.15384615384656308
```

There may be better ways to solve the problem, but I tried to answer the question in a way that's similar to writing a `while` loop. If you want to know how that `while` loop could work, there are lots of references on the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) or other scalar rootfinding algorithms.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help. I will try this method out!